# Trouble using `make-at-reader`-generated function with `include/reader`

Tags: macros, include, racket, scribble

**Edit:** I've identified the problem, and I've found a workaround (see Update 2 at the end), but it seems like there should be a more elecant way to do this — I hope someone can come up with one.

I'm running into trouble when trying to use a function I've generated using Racket/Scribble's [make-at-reader](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/reader-internals.html?q=make-at-reader#%28def._%28%28lib._scribble%2Freader..rkt%29._make-at-reader%29%29) as the *reader-expr* for `include/reader` or `include-at/relative-to/reader` (from [racket/include](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/include.html)), and I'm hoping someone can explain what I'm doing wrong.

I have used some of the arguments to `make-at-reader` to define a substantially different use for @-forms (basically for a template system), basically like this:

```
(define cmd-readtable
  (make-readtable #f #f 'non-terminating-macro <<myExtensionProcHere>>))
(define at-template-reader
  (make-at-reader #:syntax? #t               
                  #:inside? #t
                  #:command-char #\ƒ
                  #:command-readtable cmd-readtable
                  #:syntax-post-processor <<myFunctionHere>>))
```

I can get this to work ok, if not super elegantly, at run-time with `call-with-input-file`. For example, if I do,

```
((lambda (stx)
   (syntax-case stx ()
     [(a ...)
      #'(string-append a ...)]))
 (syntax->list
  (call-with-input-file
      "/path/to/my/file"
   (lambda (in)
     (at-template-reader 'test in)))))
```

I get something like,

```
'(string-append "string foo"
                "\n"
                (expression "bar")
                "string baz")
```

which, using `eval` and `namespace-anchor->namespace`, evaluates just as it should. To be explicit, all of the syntax objects correspond either to literal strings or expressions that evaluate to strings; the expressions from the external file do, however, need to have access to a parameter and some other definitions from the module's context.

However, what I would prefer to do is use something like `include/reader` or `include-at/relative-to/reader` (maybe even more similar to `include/template` from [web-server/templates](http://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server/templates.html?q=include%2Ftemplates#%28form._%28%28lib._web-server%2Ftemplates..rkt%29._include-template%29%29)) so that the work of interpreting the external file can be done at compile-time. My attempts to use my `at-template-reader` in one of those forms, though, have been totally unsuccessful: worse, they simply run with no results until they run out of memory, so I'm not even sure how to debug them. I think I'm in a bit over my head here, and I'd appreciate anyone's ideas on how to get this working.

---

**Update 1:** Asumu Takikawa asked in a comment if it works with `#:inside? #f`. I have now tried that, and it does — or at lease a much closer approximation of working that using `#:inside? #t`, which just goes off into never-never land until I kill it or it runs out of memory. The `#:inside? #f` version succeeds and returns values. (It does behave oddly with some of the logic I've defined, sometimes only returning only the last value, but I think that may be because I made some assumption that only holds for `#:inside? #t`-mode; I'm looking into that now.)

Does this give anyone an idea of what might be going wrong with the `#:inside? #t` version? I'm wondering if it might have something to do with the fact that, with `#:inside? #t`, it returns only one syntax object representing the whole external file …

---

**Update 2:**

I've identified the problem, and I've now got a very hack-ish workaround, but I hope someone can explain to me what the *right* way to do this is.

First, let me give a name to the `#:inside? #f` function I tried at Asumu Takikawa's suggestion so I can refer to it concisely:

```
(define at-template-reader-OUTSIDE
  (make-at-reader #:syntax? #t               
                  #:inside? #f
                  #:command-char #\ƒ
                  #:command-readtable cmd-readtable
                  #:syntax-post-processor <<myFunctionHere>>))
```

There is a crucial difference between the `read-syntax`-like functions I'm calling `at-template-reader` and `at-template-reader-OUTSIDE`, which I discovered by playing with `(port->list [r in])`[<sup>docs</sup>](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/port-lib.html?q=reading#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fport..rkt%29._port-~3elist%29%29) (which "returns a list whose elements are produced by calling `r` on `in` until it produces eof"). Each call to `at-template-reader-OUTSIDE` produces a single syntax object corresponding to the next chunk of the source file, as expected, until finally one produces `eof`. However, each call to `at-template-reader` produces a single syntax object corresponding to the whole source file, and never produces `eof` — calls after the first just return the empty list (as a syntax object). This means calls to `port->list` — and, it seems, `include/reader` and friends — never return.

I've gotten this working by using a wrapper function, like this: (in a module where everything is at the right phase level)

```
(include/reader (file "/path/to/source-file")
                (lambda (stx in)
                  (cond [(eof-object? (peek-char in))
                         eof]
                        [else
                         ((lambda (stx)
                            (syntax-case stx ()
                              [(a ...)
                               #'(string-append a ...)]))
                          (syntax->list
                           (at-template-reader stx in)))])))
```

However, this feels clumsy — I hope someone can tell me the "right" way to do this.

Comment: Does it work if you set the `#:inside?` argument to `#f`?

Comment: Yes, at least sort of. I'm adding the details above.